# How do I add a running total of users alongside the new users added by day?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, group-by, count

I am trying to show the new users added today, alongside the total count.

This

```
SELECT
DATE("CreatedAt"),
COUNT(DATE("CreatedAt")),
COUNT(DISTINCT"Id")

FROM "User"

GROUP BY DATE("CreatedAt")
ORDER BY DATE("CreatedAt") DESC
```

Outputs this

```
Date.         New  Total
"2020-04-21"    50  50
"2020-04-20"    40  40
"2020-04-19"    30  30
"2020-04-18"    20  20
"2020-04-17"    10  10
```

How do I display the aggregate number of users (to date) on the Total column? The 21st should read 150.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions for this: basically, you want a window sum of the count of rows per group, like:

```
select
    date("CreatedAt") created_day,
    count(*) "New",
    sum(count(*)) over(order by date("CreatedAt")) "Total"
from "User"
group by date("CreatedAt")
order by created_day desc
```